# How can I get the startIndex and endIndex of pages from document in Google Docs API?

Tags: google-docs-api

I'm working on a document who create a many tables dynamically using Google Docs API and several of these tables have images and the stylization could change when we put some images or texts, making the table growing up.

Therefore I need a command to get the start and endIndex of pages, to check after all my insertions if the tables are on one or many pages to insert new rows in the page breaks.